# Having Trouble with Push Notifications to iOS devices with FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on an app and have gotten FCM to send to notifications to Android devices, but currently having issues with sending to iOS devices.

I have followed the steps to do this as listed [here](https://medium.com/flutterpub/enabling-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-with-flutter-39b08f2ed723), which also includes the steps listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs).

Here is the FCM SDK code that I have that works with Android devices:

```
    // This assumes that you have placed the Firebase credentials in the same directory
    // as this PHP file.
    $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');

    // get our Firebase account loaded
    $firebase = (new Firebase\Factory())
            ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
        ->create();

    // create a message
    $messaging = $firebase->getMessaging();

    // Creating a notification
    $notification = Notification::fromArray([
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $body,
    ]);

    $data = [
        'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        'fromid' => $fromid,
    ];

    // Compose the message; notification + device token
    $message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $deviceToken)
        ->withNotification($notification)
        ->withData($data);


    // validate the message
    try {
        $messaging->validate($message);
    } catch (InvalidMessage $e){
        print_r($e->errors());
        exit;
    }

    // send message
    $report = $messaging->send($message);
```

I have tried sending messages through the Firebase console and using the FCM SDK; neither of which have caused a notification to appear on iOS devices.  The console gives me no feedback, but the SDK gives me an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/apwt-app1/messages:send` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATE (truncated...)
in /var/www/vhosts/globalsups/composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113

Comment: Can anyone help? Seems like Firebase is immensely broken or beyond complicated in this area.